# AngularJS select ng-options infinite digest error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-infdig

I have a select tag with a function call in ng-options:

```
<select ng-model='selectedList'
        ng-options='list.id as list.label
                    for list in listService.computeLists(resume)'
>
```

that's causing a repeating infinite digest error.

> angular.js:14525 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Is there any way to have this function call in `ng-options` without getting that error? I've tried memoizing but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not changed. See [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

Comment: Thanks! This worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each `$digest` cycle triggers a state change and subsequent `$digest` cycle. AngularJS detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>
```

```js
$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
};
```

The solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not changed.

```
var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return users;
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope/infdig)

Comment: Alternatively, if you have data that might change, you can cache the results of the function and return the cached results unless the results have changed. 
`var cache = {};
$scope.getUsers = function(input) {
    if (cache[input]) 
        return cache[input];
    else
        return cache[input] = users;
}'

Granted, the 'getUsers' function isn't the best example for this because the users likely won't change based on the input, but I'm sure you get the idea. If you have a template that you reuse in multiple places and you need data specific to each instance, this works.